# Memory limitations on db2 express-c version 10.1 seems stuck at 2 gig, why?

Tags: db2, express-edition

I just updated from 9.7 to 10.1, to leverage the new 4gig memory limitation.  However, my app only appears to be using 2.  So i searched for a way to find out how memory is used and found this command:

```
D:\DB2\scripts>db2pd -dbptnmem

Database Member 0 -- Active -- Up 0 days 04:40:54 -- Date 09/16/2012 14:37:08

Database Member Memory Controller Statistics

Controller Automatic: N
Memory Limit:         2097152 KB
Current usage:        2057664 KB
HWM usage:            2096960 KB
Cached memory:        390464 KB

Individual Memory Consumers:

Name             Mem Used (KB) HWM Used (KB) Cached (KB)
========================================================
APPL-DOMINOS              2752        160000        1024
DBMS-DB2                109888        168832           0
FMP_RESOURCES            22528         22528           0
PRIVATE                  20480         86656        9344
DB-MYAPPLI             1901760       1901760      380096
LCL-p5088                  128           128           0
LCL-p5088                  128           128           0
```

The line that really stands out is

> **Memory Limit:         2097152 KB**

What does this mean?  Why does my app not use 4 gig?  How can I change it so that it does?  Where does one configure this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the answer in the [doc](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v10r1/topic/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.config.doc/doc/t0005243.html) (I should have RTM). You check the setting using:

```
db2 get dbm cfg
```

And looking for INSTANCE_MEMORY, then update with:

```
db2 update dbm cfg using INSTANCE_MEMORY <memoryDividedBy4KB>
```

Comment: Make sure your bufferpools are set to actually use the memory. AUTOMATIC should be the default but it's always a good thing to check.

Comment: @AngerClown, would you mind expanding on that?  Which setting in particular are you talking about?

Comment: If you do a `get db cfg` make sure SELF_TUNING_MEM is set to ON. Then run ALTER BUFFERPOOL buffpoolname SIZE AUTOMATIC.

You can check current BP sizes via snapshots or with this query:
`SELECT DB_NAME, BP_NAME, BP_CUR_BUFFSZ as BP_CUR_PG_CNT, ((t.bp_cur_buffsz * bp_info.pagesize) /1048576) as  BP_MEM_MB_SIZE FROM TABLE(SNAP_GET_BP_PART('dsrdbm01',-1)) AS T, syscat.bufferpools bp_info where t.bp_name = bp_info.bpname`

Answer (score 2):

The following restrictions apply:
DB2 Express-C , Fixed Term License (FTL):
Two processor cores with a total of maximum of four cores
No more than 4 GB of memory
DB2 Express-C (no charge, non-warranted):
Up to two processor cores
No more than 2 GB of memory